# How to check all elements in array use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with array, and i have array with numbers:

```
var array = [0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54];
```

As u can see i have number, from this numbers is bigger 124, and i want to return this number.

i try to create some func:

```
 var bigestValue = array.reduce(function (a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; })
if (bigestValue <= 100) {
        return 100;
    }
```

But when script is updating it's return for me last values

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: An array is a data type of JavaScript. Why would you want to use jQuery for that? Just use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: `[0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54].find(num => num > 100);`

Comment: @ritaj func are checking all values in array, find the biggest, and retur, in my case its 124

Comment: Shouldnt the console.log be in the else part?

Comment: @ReyhanehTrb it's just example

Comment: `[0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54].sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1)[0]`

Comment: `[0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54].reduce((max, num) => num > max ? num : max, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Max number from array using

```js
var array = [0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54];
var max = array.reduce((a,b)=> a > b ? a : b,0);

console.log(max);
```

If you want to filter array by getting only elements bigger than 100, then

```js
var array = [0,10,12,23,56,111,35,66,77,124,54];
var maxArr = array.filter((a)=> a > 100);

console.log(maxArr);
```

Comment: Glad to help, Please mark the answer as accepted so it would help others facing similar issue.

Comment: Not only did you just repeat what I have already said in the comments, but your solution doesn't even work for negative numbers.

Comment: With all due respect, I did post an answer as requested by the author, Nowhere it was mentioned that he wanted this to work for negative numbers, It's approved from author for a reason